# zeromq recv data delay too much

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, zeromq

I write an example of router and dealer.

here is the server code, using router-dealer to receive data, and send data to worker for load blance, when a worker receive a message, it puts an Runnable object to ExecutorService to compute pi.:

```
public class MtServer {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MtServer.class);
private static ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

static class Worker extends Thread {
    private ZMQ.Socket worker;

    public Worker(ZMQ.Context context) {
        worker = context.socket(ZMQ.REP);
        worker.connect("inproc://workers");
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            byte[] recs = worker.recv();
            String message = new String(recs);
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            logger.info("thread[{}] receive [{}]", threadName, message);

            executors.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    double pi = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                        pi += Math.pow(-1, i) / (2 * i + 1) * 4;
                    }
                    logger.info("pi = {}", pi);
                }
            });

            logger.info("server added [{}]", message);
            worker.send(message.getBytes(), 0);
            logger.info("server send [{}] back to client", message);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    ZMQ.Socket clients = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
    clients.bind("tcp://*:5556");

    ZMQ.Socket workers = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER);
    workers.bind("inproc://workers");
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        Worker worker = new Worker(context);
        worker.start();
    }

    ZMQ.proxy(clients, workers, null);

    clients.close();
    workers.close();
    context.term();
}
```

}

client code, send a message to server every 100 ms:

```
public class HwClient extends Thread {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HwClient.class);

@Override
public void run() {
    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
    ZContext context = new ZContext();
    ZMQ.Socket requester = context.createSocket(ZMQ.REQ);
    requester.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");

    int seq = 0;
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        String message = id + "-" + seq;
        requester.send(message.getBytes(), 0);

        logger.info("client[{}] send [{}] to server", id, message);
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] r = requester.recv();
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info(id + " receive [{}] back from server spend {}ms", message, t2-t1);

        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        seq++;
    }

    context.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HwClient client = new HwClient();
    client.start();
}
```

}

My question is sometimes the delay for client recv data(t2 - t1) is too much, in my example it is up to almost 8s, and the delay is related to the execution time of computing pi, if I reduce the number of loop times in worker, the delay will reduce too, but the pi is computed in other threads!

Observing the log, most of time, when much delay is happening, the delay is happened on worker.recv in MtServer(the time between client send data and worker receive data is large), but sometimes, it's happened on submit runnable object to executors(the time between worker receive data and worker send data is large).

some log:

```
[test] 2016-02-17 15:19:11:705 INFO [Thread-0] org.test.HwClient.run(26) | client[f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e] send [f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e-3] to server
[test] 2016-02-17 15:19:19:563 INFO [pool-2-thread-2] org.test.MtServer$Worker.run(30) | thread[pool-2-thread-2] receive [f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e-3]
[test] 2016-02-17 15:19:19:563 INFO [pool-2-thread-2] org.test.MtServer$Worker.run(42) | server added [f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e-3]
[test] 2016-02-17 15:19:19:563 INFO [pool-2-thread-2] org.test.MtServer$Worker.run(44) | server send [f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e-3] back to client
[test] 2016-02-17 15:19:19:565 INFO [pool-1-thread-2] org.test.MtServer$Worker$1.run(38) | pi = 3.141592643589326
[test] 2016-02-17 15:19:19:565 INFO [pool-1-thread-1] org.test.MtServer$Worker$1.run(38) | pi = 3.141592643589326
[test] 2016-02-17 15:19:19:563 INFO [Thread-0] org.test.HwClient.run(30) | f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e receive [f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e-3] back from server spend 7858ms
[test] 2016-02-17 15:19:19:666 INFO [Thread-0] org.test.HwClient.run(26) | client[f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e] send [f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e-4] to server
[test] 2016-02-17 15:19:19:666 INFO [pool-2-thread-1] org.test.MtServer$Worker.run(30) | thread[pool-2-thread-1] receive [f11d3f6f6e9b4476a67053828c214c6e-4]
```

Can anyone help me? thanks.

Comment: It *sounds* like `executors.submit()` is blocking... is there any chance of that?  Either from the thread pool or the queue becoming overwhelmed?  How many tasks are in the queue when this is happening?

Comment: @Jason from the log, between client sends message and serve receives the message(before `executors.submit()`) is about 8s. and high latency occurs periodly, in my machine, when client sends about 30 messages, there is a high latency.